# Adding more threads to program resulted in longer execution time for calculating trapezoidal integration

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am working on a multi-threaded numerical integration program using the [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule).

I have a struct which contains six items:

```
typedef struct trapezoidalIntegrationThread{
    float a;
    float b;
    int n;
    float h;
    double res;
    float elTime;
}threadParams;
```

`a` is the left end point, `b` is the right end point, `n` is the number of trapezoids, `h` is the height, `res` is the result calculated within `compute_with_pthread`, and finally, `elTime` is the elapsed time for `compute_with_pthread` for benchmarking.

Here is my code in main:

```
int n = NUM_TRAPEZOIDS;
float a = LEFT_ENDPOINT;
float b = RIGHT_ENDPOINT;

pthread_t masterThread;
pthread_t slaveThread[NUM_THREADs];
threadParams *trapThread;

for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREADs; i++) {
    trapThread = (threadParams *) malloc(sizeof(threadParams));
    trapThread->a = a;
    trapThread->b = b;
    trapThread->n = n;
    trapThread->h = (b - a) / (float) n;

    if (pthread_create(&slaveThread[i], NULL, compute_using_pthreads, (void *) trapThread) != 0) {
        printf("Looks like something went wrong..\n");
        return -1;
    }
}

for(i = 0; i < NUM_THREADs; i++) {
    pthread_join(slaveThread[i], NULL);
}

pthread_exit((void *) masterThread);
```

I am basically creating the number of threads defined in `NUM_THREADS` (let's assume this value is `4`). I am allocating how much memory the struct needs, and setting the pre-defined values of:

```
#define LEFT_ENDPOINT 5
#define RIGHT_ENDPOINT 1000
#define NUM_TRAPEZOIDS 100000000
#define NUM_THREADs 8   /* Number of threads to run. */
```

Next, I create my pthreads, and call the `compute_using_pthreads` function:

```
void *compute_using_pthreads(void *inputs)
{
    double integral;
    int k;
    threadParams *args = (threadParams *) inputs;
    unsigned long p_micros = 0;
    float p_millis = 0.0;
    clock_t p_start, p_end;

    float a = args->a;
    float b = args->b;
    int n = args->n;
    float h = args->h;

    p_start = clock();

    integral = (f(a) + f(b))/2.0;

    for (k = 1; k <= n-1; k++) {
        integral += f(a+k*h);
    }       

    integral = integral*h;

    p_end = clock();
    p_micros = p_end - p_start;
    p_millis = p_micros / 1000;

    args->res = integral;
    args->elTime = p_millis;
}
```

I ran this program and compared it against a non-multithreaded function:

```
double compute_gold(float a, float b, int n, float h) 
{
    double integral;
    int k;

    integral = (f(a) + f(b))/2.0;

    for (k = 1; k <= n-1; k++) {
        integral += f(a+k*h);
    }

    integral = integral*h;

    return integral;
}
```

So here are the results:

Run-time of `compute_gold`:

```
~3000 ms
```

Run_time of `compute_with_pthread`:

```
Using 1 thread: ~3000 ms

Using 2 threads: ~6000 ms

Using 4 thrads: ~12000 ms

....
```

So for some reason, the more threads I added, the execution took n-threads more time to execute. I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening, as I am quite new to C programming =/

Comment: Standard warning: do not achst `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends in C! That will hide potential errors.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't every thread calculate the same thing and the same range as non-threaded version?

Comment: yes I was going to ask you to hilite where you farm out the number of tasks, it's a bit too fragmented to follow.

Comment: @jaroslawj Ouch.. Maybe that's where the issue is. How do I split the ranges up so each thread calculates something differently?

Comment: I can't see your whole code so it's hard to answer, if you are doing these calculations for NUM_TRAPEZOIDS you may split this number to NUM_TRAPEZOIDS/NUM_THREADS for each thread, but it's just my guessing...

Comment: You leak memory like a sieve. Why don't you allocate the arguments for your worker threads in one go?

Comment: @jaroslawj I'm going to try this method. What you are saying is, I can break up the `NUM_TRAPEZOIDS` to 8 chunks (assuming eight threads), is that right?

Comment: @EOF I'm not sure what you mean by this, unfortunately :/. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage yes, but I'm just guessing. If you have some external loop iterating over NUM_TRAPEZOIDS it may be some solution.

Comment: Since `NUM_TRAPEZOIDS` isn't used in any posted code, that is hard to answer.

Comment: I have updated my code to include `NUM_TRAPEZOIDS`. @WeatherVane

Comment: You leak the memory you allocate for the arguments, `trapThread`. You `malloc()` them in a loop, but never `free()` any of them.

Comment: Just like I said previously you're calculating n - 1 trapesoids in each thread and it makes no sense - because you are doing the same in each of them. Pass offset and size to each thread instead of n and modify "for (k = 1; k < n  -1) " into "for (k = offset; k < size - 1") or something similar ;) Then first thread  will count for range (0 - size -1), second (size, 2 * size) and so on...

Comment: Also, your `compute_gold()` calculates incorrect values, even for something as simple as `f(x) = x`, for which the trapezoidal integration should be exact.

Comment: regarding the call to malloc()  1) in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc as it is already a void* so can be assigned to any pointer variable.  Not casting also eliminates a potential problem when performing maintenance on the code.   2) Always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc to assure the operation was successful.  (similar considerations exist for calloc() and realloc())

Comment: in general, adding threads (or processes via fork()) will not speed up an application, unless each thread had to perform much less 'work'.  However, even then, the overall execution time will increase because of the increased work done by the OS to swap threads, start threads, end threads.   The best use for threads is when there are separate tasks to accomplish and they need to run (more or less) at the same time  and/or each thread is delayed by lots of I/O wait time